# Build a specific all-purpose initialization

Tags: ios, swift, struct, swiftui, calendar

Hi everyone I'm trying to create my own calendar within an app

I created the **CalendarLC** structure which currently needs to use an `@ObservedObject` to manage the date selected by the user ..

I am trying to structure it in such a way that I can also reuse it in other projects but I was wondering ... In case I use this calendar in a project where I don't need to use `@ObservedObject` but `@State` is there a way to structure this structure to avoid specifying @observedObject or @state? is there any particular initialization to pass an object that could have the `@ObservedObject` or `@State` property wrapper? or every time I use this structure do I have to specify the type again?

```
struct CalendarLC: View {
    
    //in another project it might be @State selectedDate: Date
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : ReservationsModel

    // Calendar Style
    // Default Vertical
    var axis: Axis.Set = .vertical
   

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Then your common component should be with state, and in the project with `ReservationsModel` just add thing wrapper around common one.

Comment: You could also make the common component a binding, and then in a parent view have either an `@State` or an `@ObservedObject` to control the data into the `CalendarLC`.

Comment: Just because it hasn't been explicitly said, I'll note that `@State` won't work properly with a reference type (a `class`) and `@ObservedObject/@StateObject` won't work properly (or at all -- compilation error) with a value type `struct`. That's why you'll have to have something like a wrapper as @Asperi suggested.

Comment: Are you saying you can't define an `@State var viewModel` variable or an `@ObservedObject var viewModel` in a parent struct, and the call `CalendarLC(viewModel: $viewModel)` if `CalendarLC's` has an `@Binding var viewModel: ViewModel` and have it work properly?